# Задание типа при создании меню в битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, интерфейс, меню, настройки

Есть три типа меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь создать новый экземпляр меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в выпадающем списке типов меню выводятся только 2 пункта - **Меню раздела, Главное меню**. Почему не отображается **Нижнее меню**? Не минусуйте, я не профи в Битриксе.

Почему не все **типы меню для первого уровня** отображаются в выпадающем списке?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что на вашем сайте уже стоит динамическое меню, а оно может быть заменено только динамическим. Поэтому для установки статического меню необходимо больше работать руками. Просмотрите урок по созданию статического меню: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=10247&LESSON_PATH=3905.4460.10227.26238.10247